# How stay on the floor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help with the code? I'm creating a parkour game and everything went well but I got stuck on it: as the cube will stand on the floor. Here is my js code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//Налаштування
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var gameOver = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Caurier";
  ctx.textAlign = "cener";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctxfillText("GAME OVER", width / 2, height / 2);
};
var cicle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}; //Людина 
//намалювати
function Draw() {
  this.x = 10;
  this.y = 10;
}
Draw.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x + 50, this.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x + 50, this.y + 50);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y + 50);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.fill();
}
Draw.prototype.move = function() {
  if (this.x < 0) {
    this.x = 0;
  } else if (this.x > 1250) {
    this.x = 1250;
  }
  if (this.y < 0) {
    this.y = 0;
  } else if (this.y > 450) {
    this.y = 450;
  }
  while (this.y < 450) {
    this.y++;
  }
}
Draw.prototype.setDirection = function(direction) {
  if (direction === "left") {
    this.x = this.x - 10;
  } else if (direction === "right") {
    this.x = this.x + 10;
  } else if (direction === "up") {
    this.y = this.y - 150;
  }
}
var person = new Draw;
var keyActions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right"
};
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  person.setDirection(direction);
});
setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1300, 500);
  person.draw();
  person.move();
  //карта
  var floor = ctx.strokeStyle = "LimeGreen";
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 312, 1300, 362);
}, 30);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(44, 235, 225);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>parcur</title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="500"></canvas>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried a lot but it didn't work out. For example, I tried this: first the code checks whether the cube and the floor are in the same coordinates, if so it reflects, if not, then no.I want the cube to be able to walk on the floor which is painted green, and not pass through it.

Comment: You have to implement some collision detection algorithm I'm afraid

Comment: Can you please help me with this?
I will be very grateful to you for that!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection